# Android when user manually removes a Google account from the device

Tags: android, google-signin, android-googleapiclient

After a user has signed into a Google account and then manually removes that Google account via settings 'Accounts' a call to `getLastSignedInAccount` returns a `GoogleSignInAccount` instead of null and a call to  vGoogleSignIn.hasPermissions` returns true.

Is there anyway to detect that an account is not active?

Presently I detect and handle it in the failure callback when an api call, which requires an authenticated user,  is made.

```
GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
if (GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions(account, getFitnessOptions())) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: in this case, `.getLastSignedInAccount()` probably should already return `null`. file an issue, because it's a certain flaw, that the account gets removed but not the reference to it.

Comment: Thanks. I filed a bug.